# POST http://localhost:8000/signup 500 (Internal Server Error) Axios React

Tags: typescript, express, axios, postman, internal-server-error

here is the error:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/signup 500 (Internal Server Error)         api.js:146

Promise.then(async)
(anonymous)    api.js:143
API.\<computed\>    api.js:142
signupUser    SignInUpPage.jsx:113
onClick    SignInUpPage.jsx:279
```

here is my **api.js** file

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  API_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGES,
  SERVICE_URLS,
} from "../constants/config.js";

//make single api with api interseptors

const API_URL = "http://localhost:8000";

const axiosInstance = axios.create(
  //make api and save it in an instance
  {
    baseURL: API_URL,
    timeout: 10000, //if delayed and api goes in pending then timeout
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  }
);

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  //intercept request
  function (config) {
    //first callback fun. in case of successful
    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    //second callback fun. in case of error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

//at the strat pf api loader is shown

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  //intercept response
  function (response) {
    //Stop global loader here
    return processResponse(response);
  },
  function (error) {
    //Stop global loader here
    return Promise.reject(processError(error));
  }
);

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// if success -> return {isSuccess: true, data: object} //200 around 202, 204
// if error -> return {isFailure: true, status: string, msg: string, code: int}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

const processResponse = (response) => {
  if (response?.status === 200) {
    return { isSuccess: true, data: response.data };
  } else {
    return {
      isFailure: true,
      status: response?.status,
      msg: response?.msg,
      code: response?.code,
    };
  }
};

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// if success -> return {isSuccess: true, data: object} //200 around 202, 204
// if error -> return {isFailure: true, status: string, msg: string, code: int}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

const processError = (error) => {
  if (error.response) {
    //if get response in error
    //request made successfully but server responded with status code other than 200
    //i.e. that falls out of the range of 2.x.x range
    // console.log("ERROR IN RESPONSE:", error.toJSON());
    console.log("ERROR IN RESPONSE:", error.response);
    return {
      isError: true,
      msg: API_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGES.responseFailure,
      code: error.response.status, //error code from backend
    };
  } else if (error.request) {
    //if get request in error
    //request made successfully but no response was received from the server
    // console.log("ERROR IN REQUSET:", error.toJSON());
    console.log("ERROR IN REQUSET:", error.request);
    return {
      isError: true,
      msg: API_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGES.requestFailure,
      code: "",
    };
  } else {
    //if gets nothing in error
    //something happened in setting up request that triggers an erro
    //i.e. some problem in frontend
    // console.log("ERROR IN NETWORK:", error.toJSON());
    console.log("ERROR IN RESPONSE:", error);
    return {
      isError: true,
      msg: API_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGES.networkError,
      code: "",
    };
  }
};


const API = {};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(SERVICE_URLS)) {
  API[key] = (body, showUploadProgress, showDownloadProgress) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axiosInstance({
        method: value.method,
        url: value.url,
        data: body,
        responseType: value.responseType,
        onUploadProgress: function (progress) {
          if (showUploadProgress) {
            let percentageCompleted = Math.round(
              (progress.loaded * 100) / progress.total
            );
            showUploadProgress(percentageCompleted);
          }
        },
        onDownloadProgress: function (progress) {
          if (showDownloadProgress) {
            let percentageCompleted = Math.round(
              (progress.loaded * 100) / progress.total
            );
            showDownloadProgress(percentageCompleted);
          }
        },
        validateStatus: (status) => {
          return true; // I'm always returning true, you may want to do it depending on the status received
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          resolve(processResponse(response));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject(processError(error));
        });
    });
  };
}


export { API };
```

here is my **SignInUpPage.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Box,
  TextField,
  Button,
  styled,
  Typography,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  Input,
  InputAdornment,
  IconButton,
} from "@mui/material";
import Visibility from "@mui/icons-material/Visibility";
import VisibilityOff from "@mui/icons-material/VisibilityOff";
import logo_image from "./../../assets/images/secondary.png";
import PersonIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Person";
import VpnKeySharpIcon from "@mui/icons-material/VpnKeySharp";
import "./../../styles/sign-in-up-page.css";
import EmailSharpIcon from "@mui/icons-material/EmailSharp";
import { API } from "./../../service/api.js";

//Styled Tags

const StyledBox = styled(Box)`
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 7px;
`;

const StyledImage = styled("img")({
  width: 200,
  margin: "0 auto 30px",
  display: "flex",
  padding: "50px 0 0",
});

// or give margin like ...
// const StyledImage = styled("img")({
//   width: 200,
//   margin: "30px auto",
//   display: "flex",
//   padding: "50px 0 0",
// });

const Wrapper = styled(Box)`
  padding: 25px 35px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  & > div,
  & > button,
  & > p {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
`;

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  text-transform: none;
  background: rgba(138, 154, 91, 1);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
`;

const StyledOtherButton = styled(Button)`
  text-transform: none;
  background: #fff;
  color: #2874f0;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: none;
`;

const Error = styled(Typography)`
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #ff6161;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
`;

const signupInitialValues = {
    email: "",
    fullname: "",
    password: "",
  };

export default function SignInUpPage() {
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickShowPassword = () => setShowPassword((show) => !show);

  const handleMouseDownPassword = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const [account, toggleAccount] = React.useState("signin");
  const [signup, setSignup] = useState(signupInitialValues);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const toggleSignup = () => {
    account === "signup" ? toggleAccount("signin") : toggleAccount("signup");
  };

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    // setSignup({ ...signup, [e.target.fullname]: e.target.value }); //fullname is key for signup object and .value corresponds to the value of the object
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setSignup({ ...signup, [name]: value });
  };

  const signupUser = async () => {
    let response = await API.userSignup(signup);
    if (response.isSuccess) {
      setError("");
      setSignup(signupInitialValues);
      toggleAccount("signin");
    } else {
      setError("Something went wrong! Please try again later.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <StyledImage src={logo_image} alt="Secondary Logo" />
      <StyledBox>
        <Box>
          {account === "signin" ? (
            <Wrapper>
              <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
                <PersonIcon
                  sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }}
                ></PersonIcon>
                <TextField
                  id="username-textfield"
                  label="Your Username or Email"
                  variant="standard"
                  sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                ></TextField>
              </Box>

              <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
                <VpnKeySharpIcon
                  sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }}
                ></VpnKeySharpIcon>
                <FormControl
                  sx={{ m: 0 }}
                  variant="standard"
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                >
                  <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">
                    Your Password
                  </InputLabel>
                  <Input
                    id="standard-adornment-password"
                    type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                    endAdornment={
                      <InputAdornment position="end">
                        <IconButton
                          aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                          onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                          onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                        >
                          {showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
                        </IconButton>
                      </InputAdornment>
                    }
                  />
                </FormControl>
              </Box>

              <StyledButton variant="contained" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                Sign in
              </StyledButton>
              {error && <Error>{error}</Error>}
              <Box
                sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end", margin: "auto" }}
              >
                <Typography
                  style={{
                    color: "grey",
                    textAlign: "center",
                    fontSize: "14px",
                  }}
                >
                  New to InkOdy?
                </Typography>

                <StyledOtherButton
                  variant="text"
                  onClick={() => toggleSignup()}
                >
                  Sign Up
                </StyledOtherButton>
              </Box>
            </Wrapper>
          ) : (
            <Wrapper>
              <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
                <PersonIcon
                  sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }}
                ></PersonIcon>
                <TextField
                  id="signup-fullname-textfield"
                  label="Your Firstname & Lastname"
                  variant="standard"
                  //   InputProps={{
                  //     endAdornment: (
                  //       <InputAdornment position="end">
                  //         <PersonIcon />
                  //       </InputAdornment>
                  //     ),
                  //   }}
                  sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                  onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
                  name="fullname"
                  //   size="small"
                ></TextField>
              </Box>

              <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
                <EmailSharpIcon
                  sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }}
                ></EmailSharpIcon>
                <TextField
                  id="email-textfield"
                  label="Enter your Email"
                  variant="standard"
                  //   InputProps={{
                  //     endAdornment: (
                  //       <InputAdornment position="end">
                  //         <PersonIcon />
                  //       </InputAdornment>
                  //     ),
                  //   }}
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
                  name="email"
                  //   size="small"
                ></TextField>
              </Box>

              <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
                <VpnKeySharpIcon
                  sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }}
                ></VpnKeySharpIcon>
                <FormControl
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  sx={{ m: 0 }}
                  variant="standard"
                  onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
                  name="password"
                >
                  <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">
                    Set Password
                  </InputLabel>
                  <Input
                    id="standard-adornment-password"
                    type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                    endAdornment={
                      <InputAdornment position="end">
                        <IconButton
                          aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                          onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                          onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                        >
                          {showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
                        </IconButton>
                      </InputAdornment>
                    }
                  />
                </FormControl>
              </Box>

              <StyledButton
                variant="contained"
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                onClick={() => signupUser()}
              >
                Sign Up
              </StyledButton>

              {error && <Error>{error}</Error>}

              <Box
                sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end", margin: "auto" }}
              >
                <Typography
                  style={{
                    color: "grey",
                    textAlign: "center",
                    fontSize: "14px",
                  }}
                >
                  Already have an account?
                </Typography>
                <StyledOtherButton
                  variant="text"
                  onClick={() => toggleSignup()}
                >
                  Sign In
                </StyledOtherButton>
              </Box>
            </Wrapper>
          )}
        </Box>
      </StyledBox>
    </>
  );
}
```

here is my app.js

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

//import connction to database
import Connection from "./database/db.js";

//import routes
import router from "./routes/route.js";

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true })); //we use the body parser because when we add invalid characters in URL like space the parser replaces it with some characters like 9%0%%
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/", router);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

const PORT = 8000;

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server is running successfully on Port ${PORT}`)
);

const USERNAME = process.env.DB_USERNAME;
const PASSWORD = process.env.DB_PASSWORD;

Connection(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

//userController.js

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import Token from './../models/Token.js';
import User from './../models/User.js';

dotenv.config(); 

export const signupUser = async (request, response) => {
    try {
        // const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
        // const hashedPass
        word = await bcrypt.hash(request.body.password, salt);
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(request.body.password, 10);

        const user = { email: request.body.email, fullname: request.body.fullname, password: hashedPassword }
        // const {email, fullname, password} = request.body;
        const newUser = new User(user);
        await newUser.save();
        // response.send(newUser);
        return response.status(200).json({ msg: 'Signup successfull' });
    } catch (error) {
        return response.status(500).json({ msg: 'Error while signing up user' });
    }
}

export const signinUser = async (request, response) => {
    let user = await User.findOne({ username: request.body.username });
    if (!user) {
        return response.status(400).json({ msg: 'Username does not match' });
    }

    try {
        let match = await bcrypt.compare(request.body.password, user.password);
        if (match) {
            const accessToken = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), process.env.ACCESS_SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: '15m'});
            const refreshToken = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), process.env.REFRESH_SECRET_KEY);
            
            const newToken = new Token({ token: refreshToken });
            await newToken.save();
        
            response.status(200).json({ accessToken: accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken,name: user.name, username: user.username });
        
        } else {
            response.status(400).json({ msg: 'Password does not match' })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).json({ msg: 'error while login the user' })
    }
}

export const signoutUser = async (request, response) => {
    const token = request.body.token;
    await Token.deleteOne({ token: token });

    response.status(204).json({ msg: 'logout successfull' });
}
```

i think the problem might lie in backend cuz there is error showing cannot GET/ on localhaost:8000 but i am exactly not able to find the origin of the problem.

**also there occurs error while verifying server side using POSTMAN**

Comment: what do your server side logs show?

Comment: @DanielA.White Server responded with 404            `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: that's not what I asked - what errors are thrown?

Comment: Stack Overflow does not exist to debug your code for you.

Comment: @DanielA.White ok sorry for the misunderstandig but there are no errors thown when i run server. the server runs successfully and also the database is connected without error. apparently server seems to be working fine.

Comment: There’s that catch where you ignore error. Try attaching a debugger